# How to redirect already authorized user back to the Previous page in identity server 4 .NET CORE?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

**Below is the code added in Auth Server and Client machine**
If any more info needed on this please comment.

**StartUp.cs -- Auth Server**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
        })
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
            .AddResourceOwnerValidator<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>() 
            /*.AddProfileService<ProfileService>()*/;

        builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();



        services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
        //services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();
    }
```

**StartUp.cs -- Client App**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:44356/";
            options.ClientId = "TestIdpApp";
            options.ResponseType = "code";
            //options.UsePkce = false;
            //options.CallbackPath = new PathString("...")                
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        });
    }
```

**ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator.cs -- Auth Server**

```
public class ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator : IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator
{
    public async Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            UserInfo user = await GetUserDetails(context.UserName, context.Password).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (user != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.ErrorMessage))
            {
                //set the result
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(
                    subject: user.UserId.ToString(),
                    authenticationMethod: "custom",
                    claims: GetUserClaims(user));
                return;
            }

            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant, user.ErrorMessage);
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant, "Invalid username or password");
        }
    }

    //build claims array from user data
    public static Claim[] GetUserClaims(UserInfo user)
    {
        return new Claim[]
        {
        new Claim("user_id", user.UserId.ToString() ?? ""),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.FirstName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Surname)) ? (user.FirstName + " " + user.Surname) : ""),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName  ?? ""),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName, user.Surname  ?? ""),
        new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, user.Email  ?? "")
        };
    }
}
```

Login Logic ---

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model, string button)
    {
        // check if we are in the context of an authorization request
        var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(model.ReturnUrl);




        if (button == "reset")
        {
            return Redirect("ResetPasswordWithoutCode");
        }
        else
        {
            // the user clicked the "cancel" button
            if (button == "cancel")
            {
                if (context != null)
                {
                    // if the user cancels, send a result back into IdentityServer as if they 
                    // denied the consent (even if this client does not require consent).
                    // this will send back an access denied OIDC error response to the client.
                    await _interaction.DenyAuthorizationAsync(context, AuthorizationError.AccessDenied);



                    // we can trust model.ReturnUrl since GetAuthorizationContextAsync returned non-null
                    if (context.IsNativeClient())
                    {
                        // The client is native, so this change in how to
                        // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
                        return this.LoadingPage("Redirect", model.ReturnUrl);
                    }



                    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    // since we don't have a valid context, then we just go back to the home page
                    return Redirect("~/");
                }
            }



            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context1 = new ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext();
                context1.UserName = model.Username;
                context1.Password = model.Password;
                // validate username/password against in-memory store
                await _resourceOwner.ValidateAsync(context1);



                if (context1.Result.Subject!=null && context1.Result.Subject.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    var user = await ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator.GetUserDetails(model.Username,model.Password).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.Username, user.UserId, user.Username, clientId: context?.Client.ClientId));



                    // only set explicit expiration here if user chooses "remember me". 
                    // otherwise we rely upon expiration configured in cookie middleware.
                    AuthenticationProperties props = null;
                    if (AccountOptions.AllowRememberLogin && model.RememberLogin)
                    {
                        props = new AuthenticationProperties
                        {
                            IsPersistent = true,
                            ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(AccountOptions.RememberMeLoginDuration)
                        };
                    };



                    // issue authentication cookie with subject ID and username
                    var isuser = new IdentityServerUser(user.UserId)
                    {
                        DisplayName = user.Username
                    };

                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, props);

                    if (context != null)
                    {
                        if (context.IsNativeClient())
                        {
                            // The client is native, so this change in how to
                            // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
                            return this.LoadingPage("Redirect", model.ReturnUrl);
                        }

                        // we can trust model.ReturnUrl since GetAuthorizationContextAsync returned non-null
                        return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                    }

                    // request for a local page
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                    }
                    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect("~/");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // user might have clicked on a malicious link - should be logged
                        throw new Exception("invalid return URL");
                    }
                }



                await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginFailureEvent(model.Username, "invalid credentials", clientId: context?.Client.ClientId));
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, AccountOptions.InvalidCredentialsErrorMessage);
            }



            // something went wrong, show form with error
            var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(model);
            return View(vm);
        }
    }
```

I'm calling a webapi to check the credentials and return info about user like First name last name.

RedirectUri - https://localhost:44356/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DTestIdpApp%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A44335%252Fsignin-oidc%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%26code_challenge%3DLEZaLWC8ShzJz6LGUsdeUPr974clsUSYVPXWDNmbwOE%26code_challenge_method%3DS256%26response_mode%3Dform_post%26nonce%3D637360236231259886.MmIxNjlhODMtZTJhYy00YzUzLTliYjMtZWJmNzM3ZjRiM2VlZmYwYzI2MDAtNWRjYS00NThlLWI4MjAtY2ViYjgxY2RlYmZi%26state%3DCfDJ8LFJDL-5o71Ao2KksnBDgPVrH1DIIiM9LZSGUG43HRwLS6OjGUiGPwZ_xxT1RVryTZh7z3zwezVbdiy1L94mFlWausuYQrDNTWtzxrpTf2CrKjHRjcUIyNt5tX_g-yZYkWvxzCiyrpxnp7cctbNGoCmj_kqidhxCWsZee_26c3eVqfJfH7XEDfKUMj2BHeKQe_Ar9f2SkZJ0SBuy6MBe6zpU7-DDOYotDn-oO5zrtaHL8GCZfSqckqalL5yaGeolZ1ZDcubY01InyrBh1NwlVQRdGZRRWIZ-WnqqFKrTboQyw4rQswR-7BaLTtL8QitRkUmwS17LBLUvXKRBs8C0NUsX9HyREnmCVG2qW6s2AVpnE4iSt4XVSRcY-crXml2FjA%26x-client-SKU%3DID_NETSTANDARD2_0%26x-client-ver%3D5.5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this in your GET Login action:

```
if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: Share some details, you don't want people to extrapolate with the details of your situation. Are you setting an application cookie from identity server when you're authenticating the user? Share some code from the auth server and you client app.

Comment: Please have a look now,if any more code is needed comment down here

Comment: What is the exception that's being raised? Also you've not posted your login logic. Are you persisting the claims identity of the user in the cookie -`HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsIdentity)`? I am guessing the exception is thrown because `this.User` is `null`. Is that correct?

Comment: No this.User is not getting null, I'm getting System.Exception: Correlation failed.
  
Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)